# Configure tex4ht for linked images

Tags: graphics, tex4ht

I have a document that is to be compiled in PDF (using `pdflatex`) and XHTML (using `tex4ht`). For the XHTML version, I wish to have the images linking to their source in a new window (`target="_blank"`).

Now, this is perfectly possible by some fiddling with `\HCode`, but I prefer not having to write this *every time* when I include a graphic in my TeX source.

Is there a `\Configure` command I can use in my `tex4ht` config file, so that an a-tag is wrapped around the resulting img-tag automatically?

Note: I noticed `\Configure{IMG}`, but I assume that's for generated images, + there is not clear "image source" variable I can use.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was wondering if that was possible or not. Thanks for the edits!

Comment: @hbro see http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn5.html#QQ1-5-28

Comment: @michal.h21 You sir, are my hero! Maybe make an actual answer out of it that I can promote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [tex4ht faq](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn5.html#QQ1-5-28):

Create custom config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{graphics*}
        {png}
        {\Link[\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png target="_blank"]{}{}%  
           \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png
              \space width="40px" height="40px" }%  
         \EndLink
         }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

compile with `htlatex texfile customcfgfile`